# How to call a function in my controller which is being used as scope for view also

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am calling the fetchData function on click of an button and it fetches the complete set of data perfectly, what I need to pass form view is the item value,

I want to reuse this function and when I call this function and pass this item value it does not call the function at all, how can I reuse this function.

```
$scope.fetchData = function(item) {
        $scope.selectedData = item;
        var entry = ServiceName.ServiceItem.query({
            item: item,
        }, function() {
            $scope.item_array = entry;
        });
    }
 if(some_condition)
 {//$stateParams.item_valis used to fetch the data
 $scope.item_array = $scope.fetchData($stateParams.item_val);
 /* this call works perfectly
 var entry = ServiceName.ServiceItem.query({
            item: $stateParams.item_val,
        }, function() {
            $scope.item_array = entry;
        }); */

 }
```

Comment: Can you not assign the anonymous function to another variable, then assign that variable to `$scope.fetchData` and then reuse it again inside your if statement?

Comment: I can't see any reason why that function wouldn't be called if the branch is taken.  However note that `.fetchData` doesn't `return` a value, it sets `$scope.item_array` directly, so you mustn't assign to `$scope.item_array` within that `if` branch.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.fetchData = function fetchData (item) {
            $scope.selectedData = item;
            var entry = ServiceName.ServiceItem.query({
                item: item,
            }, function() {
                $scope.item_array = entry;
            });
    }
```

It does return undefined (by default) because you don't return anything and you're assigning (on condition):

```
$scope.item_array = $scope.fetchData($stateParams.item_val);
```

Comment: assuming that the `.query` function is async, it's not possible for `.fetchData` to `return` anything, except perhaps a `Promise`.  It's also vey likely that the internal assignment to `.item_array` inside the callback will happen _after_ the explicit assignment to the function's `undefined` return value, so at worst the array would only be very briefly mis-assigned.

Comment: There's one right there, the second argument to the `.query` function.

Comment: Ah ok missed that but it's only an assumption. Let's wait for more data tho.